# Has_many Through associated model not found / Wrong params being passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models. One is the Property model which has two dependent models: Tenant and Invoice:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :tenants, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy
end

class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :property
 has_many :invoices, through: :properties
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :property
 has_many :tenants, through: :properties
end
```

When I try to delete an Invoice, it comes up with the following message:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TenantsController#destroy
Couldn't find Tenant with 'id'=3 [WHERE "tenants"."property_id" = $1]

I understand that when I try to destroy an Invoice, it tries to delete the associated Tenant and passes the ID=3 in the params which is the ID of the Invoice.

Here are my controllers:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!


 def destroy
  @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  @invoice = @property.invoices.find(params[:id])
  @invoice.destroy
  flash[:alert] = "Locataire supprimé."
  redirect_to user_property_invoices_path
 end
end

class TenantsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def destroy
  @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  @tenant = @property.tenants.find(params[:id])
  @tenant.destroy
  flash[:alert] = "Locataire supprimé."
  redirect_to user_properties_path
 end
end
```

Of course the param Id=3 is wrong. How do I avoid all together the associated Tenant model being deleted with Invoice?

Many thanks indeed!

Comment: Review your associations following this guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I have.... still not really clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that when I try to destroy an Invoice, it tries to delete the associated Tenant and passes the ID=3 in the params which is the ID of the Invoice.

No, even if you've specified the `dependent: :destroy`, `Rails` would delete it via database, rather than send `Http` request to deleted associated records.

> When I try to delete an Invoice, it comes up with the following message:
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TenantsController#destroy Couldn't find Tenant with 'id'=3 [WHERE "tenants"."property_id" = $1]

You're trying to delete an invoice, but the error message says, that `TenantsController#destroy` is being called.

I assume, that you used the wrong url helper something like `user_properties_tenant_path(@invoice.id)` instead of `user_properties_invoice_path(@invoice.id)`, so `TenantsController` is being called instead of `InvoicesController`

Comment: Hello Igor,the view shows: <%= link_to "Supprimer", user_property_invoices_path(@invoice), :class => "btn btn-danger btn-xs", method: :delete, data:{confirm:"Etes-vous sûr(e)?"}  %> but I get a routing error now: No route matches [DELETE] "/users/3/properties/1/invoices"

Comment: that means that you don't have this route defined in you routes.rb

Comment: resources :users do
    resources :properties do
      resources :tenants
      resources :invoices
    end
  end

Comment: you probably need to change `user_property_invoices_path(@invoice)` to `user_property_invoice_path(@invoice)`, because `[DELETE] "/users/3/properties/1/invoices/1"` route should be generated

Comment: Igor, you striked it! OK so the helper has to refer to the indivual instance of the model and not to the collection (ie: index). This makes sense but was no obious to me.... Will try to rember for the next time. THANK YOU